# GA4: How to run anchor text report?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I have an event in GTM that I've setup as below. It's configured to execute on all link clicks, and my goal is to generate a report of links clicked by anchor text and / or link URL.

[image]

I've also created custom definitions for both of these event parameters as shown here:

[image]

What I can't figure out is how to create a report that shows click volume by `click_url` or `anchor_text`. In the following example, I have rows set to the `anchor_text` dimension, and values set to `event count`.

[image]

However, I get the following message:

> No data for this combination of segments, values, filters, and date
> range.

Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there any filter you have set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your tag is functioning properly. However, the problem seems to be related to the scope setting of a particular parameter. This parameter is being sent with each event, but the issue is that it's being attributed to the wrong scope. User scopes are only relevant for parameters that are specific to individual users, like user_id. So, my suggestion would be to archive the current parameter and create a new one with the correct event scope. [image]

Comment: Great catch. It looks like it's collecting properly in debugger now.